# Bootstrap collapse and tab navigation. Collapse freezes if expanded immediately after navigating to the tab

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Simple JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p5sZJ/17/

```
<ul id="mainTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="mainTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div id="first" class="tab-pane">
    </div>

    <div id="second" class="tab-pane">
        <div id="second-accordion" class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#second-body">
                        Heading
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="second-body" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Preconditions:** 
1. Make sure the first tab is active.
2. Make sure accordion on the second tab is collapsed.

**Steps to reproduce:**
1.Click navigate to the second tab and then click on the heading of the accordion immediately.
2.Try expanding/collapsing the accordion.

**Expected result:** the accordion still works.
**Actual result:** the accordion freezes in the collapsed state and cannot be expanded.

**Note:** you may need to repeat these actions several times before the bug is reproduced.

*I am basing my question on another question that I've asked a while ago:*

[Some problems with Bootstrap collapse + Tab navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162313/some-problems-with-bootstrap-collapse-tab-navigation)

*I've also read this question, but it's also a little bit different:*

[Twitter bootstrap expand/collapse all - within bootstrap tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960248/twitter-bootstrap-expand-collapse-all-within-bootstrap-tabs)

I think the accordion stucks because the browser (I reproduced the issue in ***chrome 36.0.1985.125 m***) still thinks the accordion is hidden and doesn't fire the 'transitionend' event. The accordiong stucks in the transitioning state forever.

When I opened the tab programmatically (like in first question) I could set a timeout to resolve this issue, I don't think I can do so in this case.

**Edit:**
*Just tried in FF. Couldn't reproduce*.

**Edit 2:**
Maybe I am not completely right about the steps to reproduce the problem. Just try to do the following cycle fast:
1. Open second tab.
2. Open accordion.
3. Close accordion.
4. Open first tab.
5. Repeat from first step.

*It might be that the accordion stucks while it is in process of hiding and you click on the first tab.*

**Edit 3:**
*Yes, I think the second set of steps is the right one.*

**Edit 4:**
A link to swf file with video of me reproducing the problem.
http://1drv.ms/1ttaeJr

**My question is what is the best way to resolve this particular situation?**

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Also, are you sure it is not your computer lagging?

Comment: @snowYetis Bootstrap v2.3.1. You can see it in jsfiddle. Yes, I am pretty sure it is not my computer lagging. Were you not able to reproduce the bug in chrome?

Comment: @snowYetis I added some additional information for the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using Chrome and I cannot reproduce the problem. It might help to update to Bootstrap 3.2. If you are able to. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @snowYetis Even with the new steps? You should click on the first tab while accordion is collapsing.

Comment: @snowYetis I can't update to Bootstrap 3.2.

Comment: Works great for me. Try clearing your browser Cache.

Comment: @snowYetis I've attached a video.

Comment: @snowYetis I added more content to accordeon, so now it takes more time for it to completely collapse and you have time to click on the first tab. Here is the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p5sZJ/19/

Comment: So I think I should somehow detect that accordion is transitioning and forbid the user to navigate through the tabs while it is happening.

Comment: Sorry man, I see that there are a ton of text now, but it still does not happen for me.

Comment: Can you try it on a colleague or friends computer? See if it is happeing on a different system.

Comment: Just tried it on my home computer - same thing.